# Search a string from a Multidimensional Array List

Tags: javascript

I have an array as shown below. When I enter 3 it should display "Three" or if I enter 1, it should display "One".

```
var v1 = new Array("('one', '1)", "('Two', '2')", "('Three', '3)");
```

Comment: Do you want Java, or Javascript?  They're two completely different things, not even a little bit related.

Comment: Is mandatory to use the array in this format?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a JavaScript object literal:

```
var v1 = {
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three'
};

alert(v1['1']); // one
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/8PHj7/)